# Finding the maximum number in the array recursively

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to understand recursion by doing some codes. This code should find the maximum number in the array recursively, but for some reason it doesn't work.
Thanks for your help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array [] = {11,4,6,9,15,2};

    maxNum(array, 1, 0);

}//Main

    public static int maxNum(int array[], int maxIndex, int i)
    {
        int ans;

        if(i==array.length-1)                   //Condition Stop                                 
        {
            ans= maxIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            ans= maxNum(array, Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i]), i++);
        }
        System.out.println(array[maxIndex]);
        return ans;

    }//maxNum
}//Class
```

Comment: isn't by using the Math.max(x ,y) ?

Comment: Recursion is usually done by calling the method again with a subset of the data.  Like if you had a directory structure, you'd say "give me the biggest file in c:\".  Then you would say "give me the biggest file in "c:\userfolder1\", then for each folder in userfolder1, you'd do the same.  It breaks down the problem into smaller chunks until it reaches a simple end condition.  It looks like you're trying to re-code a for loop using recursion, which is missing the point of recursion a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that Math.max() is returning the value 11 and you are trying to pass it as maxIndex to your second call of maxNum. This is resulting into trying to access array[11] in the next call, which obviously doesn't exist and the code is resulting into `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. Another issue is that you are using a post increment for i which means, i value will be incremented always after the value is passed to maxNum. You should be changing it to ++i.

Instead of `maxNum(array, Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i]), i++);`

use

`maxNum(array, array[maxIndex]>array[i]?maxIndex:i, ++i);`

The above code will pass maxIndex or i to the next call, which will be either 0 or 1 in first recursive call to maxNum.

This code doesn't fix all your issues with code. You are printing `array[maxIndex]` which may result printing it many times. I will leave that to you to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand my mistake. I'm just not sure about the syntax that all of you correct me by using " ? " and " : "

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem with the bit `Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i])`. You are using this as the second argument for the recursive call to `maxNum()`, but you are getting a **value** from the array, rather than an **index**. In other words, you're ending up using some value like 11 or 15 from your array as an index.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array [] = {11,4,6,9,15,2};

    System.out.println(maxNum(array, 0, 1));

}//Main

    public static int maxNum(int array[], int maxIndex, int i)
    {
        int ans;
        if(i==array.length)                   //Condition Stop                                 
            ans=maxIndex;
        else
            ans=maxNum(array, (array[maxIndex]<array[i])?i:maxIndex, ++i);

        return ans;

    }//maxNum
}//Class
```

> two modifications: i++ -> ++i and Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i])
>   -> (array[maxIndex]

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in this line:
  `ans= maxNum(array, Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i]), i++);`

The second argument expects an array index. However you call it with an array value:
 `Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i])` return a value from the array not an index.

**Even when you fix this there is really no added value to recursion here.** The recursive call simply looks up the next value in the array. All you are really doing is simply iterating over the array

However if instead you built the findMax function to follow a logic like this:

- *Split the array in half call findMax for each half array*
- *Compare the results return the real maximum.*

the recursion feels less superficial

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code first time your doing something legal,trying to access index which is present in the array.But next iteration you are passing 11 as index because you find this value as the maximum,change your logic for that.

```
ans=maxNum(array, (array[maxIndex]<array[i])?i:maxIndex, ++i);
```

And this 11 index is not present in the array so you are getting this error.Next time you can try debugging your code through your IDE. This code requires debugging only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
public static main(String ar[]){
    int array [] = {11,4,6,9,15,2};
    System.out.println(array[maxNum(array, 0, 0)]);
}

public static int maxNum(int array[], int maxIndex, int i)
 {
        int ans=0;

        if(i==array.length-1)    {
            ans= maxIndex;
        }
        else     {
            ans= maxNum(array, (Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i])==array[maxIndex])?maxIndex:i, ++i);
        }
        return ans;
 }
```

Problem with your code :

`maxNum` call was passing value , instead of index .
And `++i` and `i++` are different . 
In function call , if you want to pass incremented value of `i` , use `++i` .

Answer (score 0):

In this line Math.max(array[maxIndex], array[i]) you should return the next index and not the max value found. If you return the max value, you won´t be making pair comparisons as I assume you want.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is an intricate subject. For a while a tried to solve every single problem with recursion, which is not always a good idea.

Like many already pointed out (@hasan, @Buddha, etc), in the provided example code you're mixing "values in the array" with "indexes in the array". If you're already trying to understand recursion, might as well revisit arrays.

Good approach is trying to simplify your code, e.g., you can eliminate variable `maxIndex` and rely only on `i` and `i+1`. This will make your code less error prone as you have less things to take into account.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array [] = {11,4,6,9,15,2};

    System.out.println(maxNum(array, array[0]));
}

public static int maxNum(int array[], int max)
{
    if(array.length == 0)
        return max;
    return maxNum(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length), Math.max(array[0], max));
}
```